# Java Iterator start from specific element of sorted set

Tags: java, performance, collections, iterator

I have a sorted set in Java (eg a TreeSet).
I want to have an iterator starting from a specific element of the tree and be able to go to the next or previous element (in the order of sorting).

Is there any idea of how to do this without implementing my own data structure??

Thanks

---

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that I want to do it with a naive way (if there is any) since I care about perfomance. If I had access to the implementation of the tree it would take O(1) time to do that. I want something similar.

Also feel free to suggest other (3rd party) implementations of Sorted Trees in java that supports this.

Comment: not clear: given a set {12, 42, 56} do you, in order to get {42, 56}, want to say "give me data starting with 42" or "give me data starting with the 2nd element" ?

Comment: I want to get an iterator starting from a specific element let say 42 (this would be given) and then with methods like next() / previous() to go to 56 / 12 accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To go forward from element `x` of `SortedSet s`, use `s.tailSet(x).iterator()`.

To go backwards from element `x` of `NavigableSet s` use `s.descendingSet().tailSet(x).iterator()`.

`tailSet()` and `descendingSet()` create views of the original set, `s`. Their implementation therefore can not create copies of the original set (otherwise the copy would become out of date if the viewed set were changed), and so will have O(1) performance.

A `TreeSet` is a `NavigableSet` and thus a `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep calling continue to skip that iteration until you reach the Object you are looking for. Hard to give much more information without more context

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
Iterator itr = list.iterator();
boolean skipElement = true;
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    Object element = itr.next();
    if(element.equals(myTargetElement)){ //target element is what you're comparing against to see where you want to start iterating (you didn't supply that info so not sure how you want to handle this)
        skipElement=false;
    }
    if(skipElement){
        continue;
    }
     System.out.print(element);
  }
```

this will print out the element that you want to start iterating at first.

Comment: thanx for the answer but this is not very efficient

Answer (score 1):

The iterator returned by a `TreeSet` does not support going forwards and backwards. So if going forwards and backwards is a hard requirement, you will have to create a list first and obtain a list iterator from it:

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(treeSet);
int index = list.indexOf(object);
ListIterator<T> iterator = list.listIterator(index);
```

If you want to use the iterator to modify the set, this is not an option because, obviously, you would modify the list rather than the set.

If going backwards is not a hard requirement, you can create a subset of your `TreeSet` and obtain an iterator from that:

```
Navigable<T> subset = treeSet.tailSet(object);
Iterator<T> iterator = subset.iterator();
```

This is quite fast, because `tailSet` returns a *view* of the given subset, so it doesn't require making a copy of part of the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
  TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
  for (int n : set.stream().skip(5).collect(Collectors.toList())) {
     System.out.println(n);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 0L);
TreeSet<Long> tree = new TreeSet<>(list);
tree.tailSet(4L).iterator()
```